# ksh variable substitution format?

Tags: ksh

I have variables named `var1EMI`, `var2EMI`, `var1DDE`, `var2DDE`, etc
and I need to be able to iterate over them like this;

```
for dir in var1 var2
do
  echo "EMI value for " $dir " is " ${${dir}EMI}
  echo "DDE value for " $dir " is " ${${dir}DDE}
done
```

I can't figure out how to get the `${${dir}EMI}` substitutions to resolve.

Comment: what version of ksh?

Comment: version is ksh88

Answer (score 8):

ksh 93 has a `nameref` command that lets you create "aliases" to variables:

```
var1EMI=a
var2EMI=b
for v in var1 var2; do 
  nameref var=${v}EMI
  echo "${v}EMI is $var"
done
```

```
var1EMI is a
var2EMI is b
```

---

For ksh88, you may be forced to use `eval`; replace:

```
nameref var=${v}EMI
```

with:

```
eval var=\$${v}EMI
```