# Multiple ssh sessions with different users

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh

I am writing a script that connects to multiple servers which uses 3 different users.

```
#!/bin/ksh

server1=("abc1" "abc2")
server2=("abc3" "abc4")
server3=("abc5" "abc6")

for i in "${server1[@]}"
do ssh sam@$i "some command"
done

for i in "${server2[@]}"
do ssh danny@$i "some command"
done

for i in "${server3[@]}"
do ssh robert@$i "some command"
done
```

Is there a way to combine all three `for` loops` into just one. Actually I want just want to write just one ssh for multiple connections.

I have tried putting all servers in 1 array and users in anotherlike

```
servers=("abc1" "abc2" "abc3" "abc4" "abc5" "abc6")

users=("sam" "Danny" "Robert")

for i in ${servers[@]}
do
 ssh ${users[@]}@$i "some command"
done
```

But this way the script puts each user with each server, which ends up locking the service accounts…

What I want is some script that loops all the servers and users and only match user `Sam` with array `server1` user `danny` with array `server2`  and user `robert`  with array `server3`  only.
is there a better way to match just the right user with right server in a clean and better way…

Comment: Your tags say Bash, but your hashbang says Ksh.  Which shell are you actually using?

Comment: @TobySpeighti am using ksh..

Comment: hmmm. do you need to run these sequentially? In the order specified? Is the structure of the array controlling the actions fixed? Do the user names need to be hard coded? What is the relationship between usernames and hosts? Is there a reason the usernames are not defined in your ssh_config?

Comment: The ssh sessions need to be run one after the other but can be in any order. Usernames doesn’t have to be hardcoded and usernames are the service accounts for the servers…

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Bash, as the tags say (not ksh as the shebang says), we can use a **nameref** to use the corresponding array variable given the integer identifier:

```
users=(. userxyz user123 user221)
for n in 1 2 3
do
    declare -n server=server$n
    for i in "${server[@]}"
    do ssh "${users[$n]}@$i" "some command"
    done
done
```

With a suitable `echo`, we get the same output as original script:

```
ssh userxyz@abc1 some command
ssh userxyz@abc2 some command
ssh user123@abc3 some command
ssh user123@abc4 some command
ssh user221@abc5 some command
ssh user221@abc6 some command
```

To adapt this for Korn shell, you would need to [use the `nameref` built-in command](/a/98863/112566) instead of `declare -n`.

---

A simpler approach may be just to consider the username/hostname together:

```
servers=("userxyz@abc1" "userxyz@abc2"
         "user123@abc3" "user123@abc4"
         "user221@abc5" "user221@abc6")

for i in "${servers[@]}"
do ssh "$i" "some command"
done
```

Comment: Would the script try to use each user with each server if I run the script… that would cause the account to get locked…

Comment: Replace `ssh` with a suitable `echo` to see what it will do (don't you normally do that anyway before trusting someone else's code?).

Comment: `ksh93(+)` has it's own `nameref` feature, but it doesn't work like the `bash` version. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98863/6122 for an example. . Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks @shellter.  It's 30 years or so since I last used Korn shell, so I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

If `user1` is only associated with `server1a` and `server1b`, `user2` is associated with `server2a`, `server2b` and `server2c` etc., then

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -- \
    user1 server1a server1b -- \
    user2 server2a server2b server2c -- \
    user3 server3a --

while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do
    user=$1; shift

    until [ "$1" = -- ]; do
        ssh "$user@$1" 'some command'
        shift
    done

    # Shift off that "--" delimiter
    shift
done
```

This uses the positional parameters to store the user names and the corresponding list of servers.  Since it's a single list of strings, we delimit the sections of the list containing user names and server names with `--` so that we easily can see when to expect either a new user name or the end of the list.

The outer loop loops over the sections of the list and assigns the user name to the variable `user`, while the inner loop loops over the server names and calls `ssh` until the string `--` is found.

The script is written for `/bin/sh` and would therefore also work for both `ksh` and `bash`.

Given the code above, the following `ssh` commands would get executed:

```bash
ssh user1@server1a 'some command'
ssh user1@server1b 'some command'
ssh user2@server2a 'some command'
ssh user2@server2b 'some command'
ssh user2@server2c 'some command'
ssh user3@server3a 'some command'
```

If you remove the initial `set` command, you would be able to call the script from the command line like this, for the same effect:

```bash
$ ./script user1 server1a server1b -- user2 server2a server2b server2c -- user3 server3a --
```

With an extra check (`|| [ "$#" -eq 0 ]`) in the inner loop, you could leave off that last `--` on the command line.

---

If what you want to do is to apply [the DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and only call `ssh` from a single point in your code, then lift that bit out into a function.  Here's your code, modified to do that:

```bash
#!/bin/ksh

server1=("abc1" "abc2")
server2=("abc3" "abc4")
server3=("abc5" "abc6")

process () {
    ssh "$1@$2" 'some command'
}

for server in "${server1[@]}"; do
    process sam "$server"
done

for server in "${server2[@]}"; do
    process danny "$server"
done

for server in "${server3[@]}"; do
    process robert "$server"
done
```